# Error system.collections.generis.ienumerable

Tags: c#, collections

```
string[] name = { "masha", "zhenya", "nastya" };
string[] m = (from g in name  select name).ToArray<string>();//error here
```

> error system.collections.generis.ienumerable doesnot
>   conatain a definition to Array

Comment: Just `.ToArray();` no generics; do not forget add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

You should include a reference to `System.Linq` and change `select name` to `select g`.